# List of DisposableLazy`2 does not have 'Add' method when called using dynamic variable

Tags: dynamic, reflection, mef, lazy-evaluation

### Problem

I am facing a problem using dynamically created list of items when `Add` method is called on `dynamic`variable. Consider following code.

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> plugins = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)field.GetValue(instance);
if (plugins == null)
  continue;

dynamic filteredPlugins = null;
foreach (var plugin in plugins)
{
  if (filteredPlugins == null)
  filteredPlugins = Activator
    .CreateInstance(typeof(List<>)
    .MakeGenericType(plugin.GetType()));

if (/* this condition does not matter*/)
  //filteredPlugins.Add(plugin);
  filteredPlugins.GetType().GetMethod("Add")
    .Invoke(filteredPlugins, new object[] { plugin });
}
```

And now, the commented line `filteredPlugins.Add(plugin)` will throw `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` with the message `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add'` when `plugin` is of type

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.DisposableLazy<IPlugin,IMetadata>
```

but it works completely perfect when `plugin`is of type

```
System.Lazy<IPlugin, IMetadata>
```

When the reflection is used to call `Add` method on the instance `filteredPlugins` instance as is done on the next line - everything works fine for any type.

My question is **WHY** is not `Add` method found in case of `DisposableLazy` type.

### Background

This code is part of the method that I use in `OnImportsSatisfied()` method. I am using two kinds of import - which differs only in `RequiredCreationPolicy` - on has `CreationPolicy.NonShared` and the other default value of `CreationPolicy.Any`.

```
[ImportMany(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
private IEnumerable<Lazy<IPlugin, IMetadata>> plugins = null;
```

For `CreationPolicy.NonShared` fields the underlaying type in the `plugins` is `DisposableLazy` and for `CreationPolicy.Any` the underlaying type in the `plugins` is `Lazy`.

**Edit:** As asked in the answer - I am using `dynamic` variable because `IPlugin` interface can change everytime this method is called and they do not have to have anything in common.

**Edit2:** I just found similar question [C# dynamic type gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338429/c-sharp-dynamic-type-gotcha), so this can be probably closed as duplicite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.DisposableLazy` is a `private` class, the runtime binder is having trouble believing you have permission to use type, where reflection doesn't care.

Which begs the question why are you using dynamics at all in this case.  Since `DisposableLazy<IPlugin,IMetadata>` public interface is it's subclass `Lazy<IPlugin, IMetadata>` & `IDisposable`, shouldn't you just be using a `List<Lazy<IPlugin, IMetadata>>` for either case?

```
var plugins = (IEnumerable<Lazy<IPlugin, IMetadata>>)field.GetValue(instance);
if (plugins == null)
  continue;

var filteredPlugins = new List<Lazy<IPlugin, IMetadata>>();
foreach (var plugin in plugins)
{
  if (/* this condition does not matter*/)
     filteredPlugins.Add(plugin);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using `dynamic` because `IPlugin` can be (and it is) different interface for different calls of this method. I just forget to mention that in my question. I do not mind using reflection and was wondering if with `dynamic` variable the reason is realy privacy of the type.

Comment: I just found similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338429/c-sharp-dynamic-type-gotcha, accepting this as the answer.