# Cannot perform runtime binding using dynamic object that was loaded from external assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have the following code that calls getReport method from external assembly:

```
public class Loader
{
    private dynamic _devxReport;
    private XtraReport _report;

    public void LoadReport(string resourceName, string className)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resourceName));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(className));
        var asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(resourceName));
        _devxReport = asm.CreateInstance(className);               
    }

    public void CreateReport(DataSet ds)
    {
        if (ds == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ds));
        _report = _devxReport.getReport(ds);
    }
}
```

`resourceName` variable is a name of external assembly  which contains `className` . Internally `className` contains the following code

```
public class reportClass : IReports, IReportLogo
{
    public XtraReport getReport(DataSet reportData)
    {
        XtraReport report = new rptClass();
        report.DataSource = reportData;
        return report;
    }
}
```

`IReports` actually an external  interface from another common assembly

```
public interface IReports
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    XtraReport getReport(DataSet dsReportData);       
}
```

So the issue is when I try to execute Loader.CreateReport method I receive following exception

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'getReport'
```

In case I change the `dynamic` variable to `IReports` and cast instance to this interface explicitly then  everything works. This is the working code.

```
public class Loader
{
    private IReports _devxReport;
    private XtraReport _report;

    public void LoadReport(string resourceName, string className)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resourceName));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(className));
        var asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(resourceName));//resourceName);
        _devxReport = (IReports)asm.CreateInstance(className);               
    }

    public void CreateReport(DataSet ds)
    {
        if (ds == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ds));
        _report = _devxReport.getReport(ds);
    }
}
```

So  my question is how that can  happen that DLR cannot resolve runtime binding to a method that actually exist in object but if cast explicitly everything will be ok? My issue is that I cant change the code in calling assembly so in interface also.  But I want to call different method from a calling class which is not in the interface but actually also exist there.

Comment: There is an great explanation here why your solution does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338429/c-sharp-dynamic-type-gotcha

Comment: Thanks a  lot for an article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private dynamic _devxReport;
_report = _devxReport.getReport(ds);
```

The `_devxReport` has `dynamic` type. The anonymous type is `internal` to the assembly and the compiler wouldn't know which property or methods are available for the object. So, you should use a known type class instead of anonymous type to reach members in compile time.

For second example;

```
private IReports _devxReport;
_report = _devxReport.getReport(ds);
```

Now, the compiler knows which members are available for `_devxReport` object via as a known type. So, If you don't able to specify known type, your best choice is applying `Invoke` by `Reflection`.

Comment: "The anonymous type is 'internal' to the assembly" - does it mean that dynamics will never work with types from  another assemblies? Or maybe there is a way to make anonymous type 'public'?

Comment: "does it mean that dynamics will never work with types from another assemblies", No I didn't mean that. You can't get intellisense for dynamic types in the compiler time. If you want to provide it, cast it to a known type as second example.

Comment: No , I mean if I will try to load type from  another assembly and assign it to dynamic object there's no  way I will be able to call  methods from  this object without explicit cast to some real interface? Am I right or not?

Comment: Also regarding "The anonymous type is internal to the assembly and the compiler wouldn't know which property or methods are available for the object" - why compiler should know about that? I thought that the purpose of using dynamics - to postpone method resolution till runtime.