# cannot await dynamic for non public types

Tags: c#

Consider we have a task helper, who has a method named `AwaitObject` that is used for awaiting an object if it can be awaited.

```
public static class TaskHelper
{
    private static readonly Type TypeOfVoidTaskResult = Type.GetType("System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult");
    private static readonly Type TypeOfTaskOfVoidTaskResult = typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(TypeOfVoidTaskResult);

    public static async Task<object> AwaitObject(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        var type = obj.GetType();

        if (type == typeof(Task)
            || type == typeof(ValueTask)
            || type == TypeOfTaskOfVoidTaskResult)
        {
            await (dynamic)obj;
            return null;
        }

        if (type.IsGenericType
            && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() is var genericType
            && (genericType == typeof(Task<>) || genericType == typeof(ValueTask<>)))
        {
            object result = await (dynamic)obj;
            return result;
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

Now we have two test cases:

```
internal class InternalClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public async Task AwaitDynamic_TaskOfInternalClass_Tests()
{
    var task = Task.FromResult(new InternalClass { Value = 1 });
    var result = await TaskHelper.AwaitObject(task);
    Assert.True(result is InternalClass { Value: 1 });
}

[Fact]
public async Task AwaitDynamic_ValueTaskOfInternalClass_Tests()
{
    var task = ValueTask.FromResult(new InternalClass { Value = 1 });
    var result = await TaskHelper.AwaitObject(task);
    Assert.True(result is InternalClass { Value: 1 });
}
```

Here is the problem.

- When `TaskHelper` and test cases are in the same assembly, all the cases will be passed.
- when I move `TaskHelper` to another assembly and then run the two tests, I will get the following exceptions.

```
For test 1#, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException that says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'". 
For test 2#, Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException that says "'System.ValueType' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'".
```

- when I move `TaskHelper` to another assembly and change `InternalClass` to `public`, all the cases will be passed.

It seems a dynamic value cannot be awaited if it is invisible.
Is there something wrong with my code?
Or is that how dynamic works. If so, why?
And how do I make `TaskHelper.AwaitObject` work properly.

Answer (score 0):

> And how do I make TaskHelper.AwaitObject work properly.

As an option replace this:

```
object result = await (dynamic)obj;
```

To this:

```
var task = (Task) obj;
await ((Task) obj).ConfigureAwait(false);
object result = task.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Task<object>.Result)).GetValue(task);
```

> Or is that how dynamic works. If so, why?

Yes, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15341641/984299) answer is fully covers the question.

Comment: Thanks, reflection is a good way. FYI, ValueTask can be converted to Task and then your code can be reused. Actually, I used reflection before and then changed to use `await dynamic` because of better performance, until I got the exceptions

Comment: @huoshan12345 I actually tested with the ValueTask and it works as it is.